# Attempt to invoke virtual method: a null object reference

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting a `Null Object Reference` and the app crashes when I sign out.

Code:

```
 //Get Comments Count
firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + postId + "/Comments").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

        if (!documentSnapshots.isEmpty())
        {
            int count = documentSnapshots.size();
            holder.updateCommentsCount(count);
        }
        else if(documentSnapshots.isEmpty())
        {
            holder.updateCommentsCount(0);
        }
    }
});
```

Error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.isEmpty()' on a null object reference

Comment: Please add you database structure.

Answer (score 1):

Your app crashes because you have not initalized `QuerySnapshot` and it is null.

```
private QuerySnapshot querySnap;
```

Initalize QuerySnapshot in the onCreate with

```
querysnap = new QuerySnapshot (this, " ");
```

**EDIT:**

Give the `@Nullable` before `QuerySnapshot` & `Exception` and an error callback after it.

```
public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
if (e != null) {
          //          Log.w(TAG, "this is the error", e);
                    return;
                }
        if (!documentSnapshots.isEmpty())
            {
```

**OR** check the answer suggested by Frank. It's a good practice to unsubscribe once you want to stop listening to updates.

Comment: Sir, I am using recyclerViewAdapter. The error is in Adapter class. Then sir where I will place QuerySnapshot

Comment: Sir I have solved this issue now by adding (Activity) context. Code: addSnapshotListener((Activity) context, new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>()

Comment: But now I am facing the other issue. Now my posts are not in order.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `QuerySnapshot` passed into `onEvent` can be null, and you'll have to guard against that in your code:

```
public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
    if (documentSnapshots == null || documentSnapshots.isEmpty())
    {
        holder.updateCommentsCount(0);
    }
    else
    {
        int count = documentSnapshots.size();
        holder.updateCommentsCount(count);
    }
}
```

The reason the `documentSnapshots` becomes null is likely that your app loses access to the specific data this code is observing once the user signs out. You may want to consider first [detaching all listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener) before signing the user out.

Comment: I completed the code snippet for you. Note that I **highly** recommend you spend some time learning how to troubleshoot and prevent null pointer exceptions like this, as they are incredibly common when you're just getting started. For a good explanation, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Sir I have solved this issue now by adding (Activity) context.
Code:

addSnapshotListener((Activity) context, new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>()

Comment: But now I am facing the other issue. Now my posts are not in order.

Answer (score 0):

try this code, it's work properly 
I also face the same problem and solve this way.

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + blogPostId + "/Likes").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

        if(queryDocumentSnapshots != null){

            if(!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()){

                int count = queryDocumentSnapshots.size();

                holder.updateLikesCount(count);
            }
            else {
                holder.updateLikesCount(0);
            }


        }
    }
});
```